# How to use secure string parameter in Add dymamic content

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have one parameter created which is of type "SecureString" . I want to use that directly in any AddDynamiccontent box .

But it throws me the error like its ecpecting the type string but the passed is "SecureString"

How to pass /convert it?

Comment: did you try `@json(string(pipeline().parameters.secparam)).value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Now to convert to string :

[image]

Output :
[image]

So to get Specific value:
[image]

Output:
[image]